# Relationship under relationship or child relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

Model.php

```
public function item(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
}
```

Result:

[image]

Is it possible to get the details of the fk uom_id under the relationship 'item'? If possible then how? I'm very new in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a relationship in your Item class like so:

```
public function uom(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Uom');
}
```

And a new model class called Uom, then you can access it `$model->item->uom`

This will try to get a record from the uom table with an id that matched uom_id on your item ([one-to-many relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)).